What 80's movie am I thinking of?
This is all I remember:
There are Dwarf/Elves/Gnomes that resemble the ones from the Movie Legend w/ Tom Cruise. NOT GUMP the Fairy. The other ones and a guy who was with them. It was a 80's fantasy movie I believe. In one scene I remember they are in the "real" world because they were hiding behind cars or something in the parking lot of a building maybe a store (I believe they came back to real world for something). 
Second Scene I remember was in the fantasy world I believe and they were in a dome like kindom/Castle thing where the "bad guy/king" was and they were being forced to walk down what I believe to be a gold in color isle to get to him ... ugh this is all I remember but it is driving me crazy someone please help. 
Thanks. 

For some reason I keep thinking of the labyrinth, but I know it's not that

I'm guessing Masters of the Universe (1987)

A prince turned warrior named He-Man battles against the dark lord Skeletor on the planet Eternia. He-Man and his comrades arrive on Earth and discover two teenage lovers to find the magical Cosmic Key


The Dwarf/Elf/Gnome is Gwildor
 [Source]
Hiding behind a car (which together with the heroes gets teleported to Eternia)
 [Source]
Golden 'isle'
 [Source]

Watch the Trailer
Watch a Making-Of



"I HAVE THE POWEEEEEEEER" - what a film :)

AHHH! THAT IS IT!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! MUST WATCH THIS AGAIN!!!!
